# MySQL query to delete records in Table A where email matches in Table B

Tags: mysql

I have a common column in two tables called 'email' where I need to remove records from Table A when a match if found in Table B.

Will this work?  Is there a better way to do this?

```
DELETE b.* FROM `tableA` b
JOIN `tableB` u
ON u.email = b.email
```

Comment: `DELETE b FROM \`tableA\` b ......` -- try that.

Comment: `DELETE b FROM tablea b`? This is deranged. Why not call tableb `a`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM tableA WHERE email IN (SELECT email FROM tableB)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
DELETE FROM TableA WHERE email IN (SELECT b FROM TableB)
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `*`

```
DELETE b 
FROM `tableA` b
JOIN `tableB` u ON u.email = b.email
```